# How can I interpret the results of my loss functions?

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, yolo

I use yolov8 for object detection. The results for my training look like this:

[image: results]

As you can see in general my validation losses are quite higher than my training losses. Here the comparison of box_loss as example:

[image: box_loss]

By searching on the internet I found the following regarding this:

> “This happens when the data available during training is not enough to
> capture the model, relative to the validation dataset.”

in https://www.baeldung.com/cs/learning-curve-ml is this the only explanation or is this gap also an indication for overfitting?

The second thing is that my validation dfl_loss is not improving at all. In the internet I found that

> "dfl_loss measures the displacement between the predicted and ground
> truth feature locations in the convolutional feature maps."

I'm not really sure what that means and how I can improve that.